# Ephemeral Diffie-Hellman Java Key Exchange

Tags: java, diffie-hellman

This is my first post on stackoverflow. I've always found what I needed but today I have to ask a question.

I am writing a program in which I want to connect to the server. The server encrypts data with the Diffie-Hellman algorithm.

And here the server code [C++]

```
///// SEND KEY
Integer p("0xB10B8F96A080E01DDE92DE5EAE5D54EC52C99FBCFB06A3C6"
"9A6A9DCA52D23B616073E28675A23D189838EF1E2EE652C0"
"13ECB4AEA906112324975C3CD49B83BFACCBDD7D90C4BD70"
"98488E9C219A73724EFFD6FAE5644738FAA31A4FF55BCCC0"
"A151AF5F0DC8B4BD45BF37DF365C1A65E68CFDA76D4DA708"
"DF1FB2BC2E4A4371");

Integer g("0xA4D1CBD5C3FD34126765A442EFB99905F8104DD258AC507F"
"D6406CFF14266D31266FEA1E5C41564B777E690F5504F213"
"160217B4B01B886A5E91547F9E2749F4D7FBD7D3B9A92EE1"
"909D0D2263F80A76A6A24C087A091F531DBF0A0169B6A28A"
"D662A4D18E73AFA32D779D5918D08BC8858F4DCEF97C2A24"
"855E6EEB22B3B2E5");

Integer q("0xF518AA8781A8DF278ABA4E7D64B7CB9D49462353");

AutoSeededRandomPool asrp;

dh_.AccessGroupParameters().Initialize(p, q, g);

p = dh_.GetGroupParameters().GetModulus();
q = dh_.GetGroupParameters().GetSubgroupOrder();
g = dh_.GetGroupParameters().GetGenerator();

Integer v = ModularExponentiation(g, q, p);

SecByteBlock spubkey(dh2_.StaticPublicKeyLength());
SecByteBlock epubkey(dh2_.EphemeralPublicKeyLength());

sprivkey.New(dh2_.StaticPrivateKeyLength());
eprivkey.New(dh2_.EphemeralPrivateKeyLength());

dh2_.GenerateStaticKeyPair(asrp, sprivkey, spubkey);
dh2_.GenerateEphemeralKeyPair(asrp, eprivkey, epubkey);

send(spubkey, epubkey);


///////// KEY AGREE
//buf = recived keys [spubkey+epubkey]
const size_t spub_key_length = dh2_.StaticPublicKeyLength();
shared_.New(dh2_.AgreedValueLength());
dh2_.Agree(shared_, sprivkey, eprivkey, buf, buf + spub_key_length)
```

I now want to exchange keys with the program in JAVA.

I don't really understand how to do it. And all examples in JAVA do not include the parameter q and Ephemeral Key.

Stackoverflow. I hope you will help me! 
I'm sitting on it a few good days...

Thank you